# Why tensorflow is slower with GPU instead of CPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

This is a really simple neural network:

```
n_pts = 500000
np.random.seed(0)
Xa = np.array([np.random.normal(13, 2, n_pts),
           np.random.normal(12, 2, n_pts)]).T
Xb = np.array([np.random.normal(8, 2, n_pts),
           np.random.normal(6, 2, n_pts)]).T

X = np.vstack((Xa, Xb))
y = np.matrix(np.append(np.zeros(n_pts), np.ones(n_pts))).T


# Create a new Keras model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=1, input_shape=(2,), activation='sigmoid'))
adam = Adam(lr=0.1)
model.compile(adam, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
h = model.fit(x=X, y=y, verbose=1, batch_size=100000, epochs=15, shuffle='true')
```

I increase the batch size up to 100k but the cpu is faster than the gpu (9 second vs 12 with high batch size and more than 4x faster with smaller batch size)
The cpu is the intel i7-8850H and the GPU is the Nvidia Quadro p600 4gb.
I installed tensorflow 1.14.0.
With a more complex network like this one:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(24, 5, 5, subsample=(2, 2), input_shape=(66, 200, 
3), activation='elu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(36, 5, 5, subsample=(2, 2), activation='elu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(48, 5, 5, subsample=(2, 2), activation='elu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='elu'))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='elu'))
# model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'elu'))
#   model.add(Dropout(0.5))

 model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'elu'))
#   model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'elu'))
#   model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(1))

optimizer = Adam(lr=1e-3)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer)
```

will a GPU be faster than the cpu?
What is necessary to do to take advantage of the gpu power?

Comment: A trivial network like this first example requires very little computation. In cases like that, the overhead of copying the data to GPU memory will be bigger than the computation itself. Even if you use bigger batches, that will scale the memory overhead as well. This can happen in relatively small networks too, with a few layers and not many units in each. The second network is more likely to benefit from the GPU. In any case the [performance of the input pipeline](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets) can make a big difference.

Comment: Maybe by reading this: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/multi_gpu_model you'll see that a single GPU does not forcingly outperform a single CPU. If you had multiple GPUs, you could parallelize the training, meaning you gain quasi-linear speedup.

Comment: Thank jdehesa and GrizZ for your excellent answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPUs work best with massively parallel workloads, your simple model is not able to achieve that. Data needs to be transfered between CPU and GPU, so if this overhead is bigger than the actual computation, then the CPU will most likely be faster, as no transfer overhead happens.

Only a much bigger model would be able to profit from GPU acceleration.